# Redux saga using dispatch for every page

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga

Hi I was working around with redux saga and had my code in dispatching actions in every page like this:

`props.dipatch({type:'GET_ACCOUNTS', params:{}})`

I have seen the documentation and other styles they define actions and action types like:

```
   getall(action) {
        dispatch({type:'GET_ACTION', action})
    }
```

But this can make code re do all over again... My question is should I switch on defining the actions like what was recommended or continue with what I am doing which is quite working anyways?

Comment: Not sure where you found the `action` property name. If anything, there is the standard flux action which uses `payload`. https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action ... either way, only required property is the type, everything else is up to you, if your current solution works fine then there is no need to rewrite it.

Comment: Regarding the standard action, while using `payload` is pretty common, the `error` field not so much. People generally tend to solve errors using separate type, see https://twitter.com/acemarke/status/1083767611299639296

Comment: The action property name is passed from the method outside that function.

example I use getall({user:1}) it is like the payload. I just named it action.